I want to move an object but all that gets moved is a little orange dot than seems it´s pivot, help!
I have an object that I want to mirror and move. But if I try to move it, I find that the axis move a little orange dot that seems to be the center pivot of the object, but it doesn´t move the object.
I dont´know how to get rid of that situation. All I can move is that orange dot.
How can I solve this? I don´t even know how to name the problem in order to search the solution…
I have a video here on the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fw1M3Np1wWYNYam2X0B9Rbzu8j3L91ni/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance :)

Maybe disable the Transform Affect Only Origins option?


Just typed the same thing, but you were first)))
